# Where to learn Combinatorics & Graph Theory further?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So far I have learned this subject for 1 year, and I really enjoyed it, I found the theorems and proofs very interesting, but the subject is over. I want to ask your opninion, where could I learn it further, and what may be still worth to know about, since I find this subject very useful in many mathematical problems, and I may never know, when I could use this knowledge in the future. :)

So, in my two semesters, at first, we learnt about the basic definitions, and after that, we started planar graphs, perfect graphs, chromatic number, Ramsey, and Turán-related theorems, and we finished with Hypergraphs(theorems like Fisher Inequality, and Erdos-Ko-Rado theorem).

If you can recommend a book, or an online site, where I can learn things, which are still "worth" to learn about, please tell me about it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you may find useful this (modest) list of exercises from graph theory http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=Graph_theory

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different directions you could go depending on what really interested you the most. Here are a few ideas:

- [Diestel](http://diestel-graph-theory.com/basic.html?) has a few chapters you might find interesting. Chapter 8 on Infinite Graphs, Chapter 11 on Random Graphs, and Chapter 12 provides an especially good overview of the [Graph Minor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robertson%E2%80%93Seymour_theorem).
- Mohar and Thomassen's [Graphs on Surfaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801866898) is a great book on topological graph theory.
- Bollobás's [Extremal Graph Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486435962) builds on the Ramsey and Turán results you learned.
- Bollobás's [Random Graphs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521797225) builds on Diestel's chapter, if you enjoy that.
- Godsil & Royle have a good introductory book for [Algebraic Graph Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952209).
- Oxley's [Matroid Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199603391) is a great reference for the subject, and there are a ton of really interesting, deep results related to graph theory.

I would also suggest talking to professors at your University that work on graph theory and combinatorics. You might be able to do a reading course in the subject, or even some of your own original research. Graph theory is fairly easy to start research as an undergrad, compared to other topics.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. :)